# Automatic update of MYSQL table according to date

Tags: php, mysql, modeling

I have a `MYSQL` table that holds events information. I need a mechanism that updates the status of each event according to its date ("over" if its a past date).
What´s the best way to do such a thing? Update the status of the event when the any user logs in (useless routine for most users), create some sort of internal task (like a cron job?), or any other way.
Right now, the status of the event is updated only when the creator logs in. This works but another user will see event as "scheduled" until the creator logs in, even if the date is past. Im using `PHP` by the way. Thanks

Comment: update it when event being requested.

Comment: The date is the only criteria? Then why do you have to update anything? Use some date arithmetics instead like e.g. comparing the date value against now().

Comment: thats a good point, but the application relies heavily on the events status, so comparing dates constantly is not an option. It would make sense if the status was requested only a few times. Updating on request is an option. I thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend updating the status any time the status is requested. Or better yet, don't even store the status in the database at all, but just compute it each time it's requested based on the other variables. So that way whenever you have a table list the status or someone request the status, just take the event date, compare it to today's date, and send them "not started", "ongoing", or "over".

Unless of course you need more possible statuses ("planning", "preparing", "setting up", etc). Then you would either need scheduled dates/times for each of these statuses or you would need to store a status variable. Either way, you could update the status (according to today's date and any other pertinent information) at the time that it's requested.

Comment: Update on request is the definitely the way to go. Not storing the status in the database would make everything more complex. Listing past events is a common task in the application and that would take a lot of processing each time a list is requested. There is too much stuff depending on events status. Thanks though.

Comment: @JoaoPedro, the fact that there is 'too much stuff' depending on the event status does not necessarily justify storing extra data in the DB - actually on the contrary; most DB systems are I/O bound, which means they are waiting for data to be read/written to and from the storage and adding extra unnecessary and extremely cheaply computable column to the mix would normally slow(!) the system. Not by much for a single field (plus index), but if employed as a principle, then it stacks up.

Answer (score 0):

Updating at user logging in is not very good idea as it adds too much pressure (if there are a lot of users). The best way to do this would be to run a cronjob every night after 12 am/ or at the beginning of the day. If you still want to keep your old code, then wrap it with a date code.
pseudo will look like:

```
$updated_last = last modification time of the file "updated";
if($updated_last is more than 1 day) {
 update db; (your old code)
 touch file "updated";
}
```

Comment: I figured a cron job wont do it, as the event status may be requested and changed to "over" just a few hours after event creation. Thanks though

Comment: @JoaoPedro "the event status may be requested and changed to "over" just a few hours after event creation". Is that not the correct operation? With a status based on a date, the status woud change at midnight, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
UPDATE events SET status = 'over' WHERE DATE(event_date) > NOW();
```

Run it every day, once a day, with [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a midnight cron job unless you have to deal with lots of timezones. Recomputing seems rather wasteful and computing on demand could get rather messy from a maintenance point of view as it leaves the data base in a partially incorrect state.

Answer (score 0):

Every answer accepts your reason for the UPDATE.
However, let me question that decision with extension to Col. Srapnel's suggestion from comments.

Updating can be seen as a waste of resources since you can calculate it on the run with in memory date comparison (which is orders of magnitude faster then I/O to storage).

There are two approaches to this:

- query/view can do this (and the cost should really be neglible)
- actually doing this on php side after results are retrieved (consider it a formatting/presentation task)
- it could even be done on the client side, which if possible, performance wise would be the best solutions (this might lead to maintenance/security issues)

Of course, there could be valid reasons for ignoring these solutions, but I think the performance by itself is not enough (most DBs are I/O bound).